# How can i send and collect data from external sources in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, category-products, helper

i'm pretty beginners in magento. i'm trying to building a test module myself .i need to know how can i send data from magento  to external sources for verification(suppose system data) and collect verified data in return . as per i get i have to use curl request for sending data to external sources. 
is there any better approach for sending and collecting data from external sources in magento

```
public function Mytestmethod($data)
{
    $cURL = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.sample.com/magento/connection/Final/external.php?order_id=<?php echo $incrementid ?>"); 
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_exec($cURL); 
    curl_close($cURL);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The querying of third party services is a reasonably common requirement. Intuitively, the way I would implement it would be to implement a model, that wrapped the API such that I can query for the data as normal with the Magento primitives.

One such implementation is here: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/NewRelic/blob/master/app/code/community/ProxiBlue/NewRelic/Model/Api.php#L65-L92

I have annotated it so that it is easier to read and understand

```
    class ProxiBlue_NewRelic_Model_Api
    {

    // ... Some other methods. Check the link

    /**
     * This is the function. Generally speaking, Magento works in terms of  "getters" and "setters" -- making the
     * data available via getter in the Model follows the principle of least suprise.
     */
    public function getAccountDetails()
    {
        // This is a simple key -> value pair of headers to send. It's not to important to understand, except
        // to note where it's used.
        $headers = array(
            'x-api-key:' . $this->_api_key
        );

        // Magento provides a series of primitives for working with APIs, that abstract the underlying connection
        // semantics (so, whether it's cURL or writing to a socket). Here, the Varien_Http_Adapter_cURL is used,
        // but I recommend you look at Zend_Http and friends.
        $http = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();

        // A request is formulated using the above constructed primitive.
        $http->write('GET', 'https://api.newrelic.com/api/v1/accounts.xml', '1.1', $headers);
        $read = $http->read();

        // Here, the response is also converted into an object such that it's easier to work with. This enables
        // nicities such as error code checking, etc.
        $response = Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($read);

        try {
            // Here, we query the response for the data we read. The construct of this is beyond the scope of this
            // question, but this gives you some idea.
            $xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($response);
            $data = (string)$xmlObj->foo->bar->baz
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return array('error' => $read);
        }
    }
```

More generally, the lessons to draw from this are:

1. This is an extremely common requirement. I picked the above example up of GitHub; i suggest you look for some more.
   Sitewards, Fontis, AOE and many other companies all put out quality extensions for reference.
2. Magento provides HTTP primitives for working with third party APIs. Take a look around at Zend_Http, or it's Varien
   children.